# How can I intercept the mass-assignment hash for an ActiveRecord object and filter it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have a record class `Person` with an integer field `awesomeness`.

If I call `Person.new(:awesomeness => 5)`, it works fine.

If I call `Person.new(:awesomeness => 'five')`, as expected, Rails does its bets to figure out what `'five'` is as an integer and fails, so it just defaults to `0`. Can I intervene by intercepting the hash and fidgeting with the data somehow?

The earliest "event" in the ActiveRecord callbacks is the `before_save`, by which point 'five' has already become `0`.

I could obviously do this controller-side, but this seems to be something that belongs strictly in the model as a filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say this actually does belong in the controller.

The job of the controller is to interpret data and interaction between the model and the view. If the model declares a field to be an integer, model logic should only be required to deal with data given as integers.

I'm assuming this "five" is coming from the view, in which case, it should be the controller's job to properly handle the data so that it's understood by the model.

Comment: Thanks for your well-reasoned arguments. My instinct was to put this in the model to be DRY, but I do agree with your high-level assessment of the situation. It's not too difficult to write in `before_filter :preprocess_phone_number, :only => [:create, :update]`.

Comment: Great. That's what I would've recommended. Do you mind accepting this as an answer?